# Expression expected in Unit Test with Moq in VB

Tags: vb.net, mocking, moq

I try to implement an authentication mock and I'd like to use [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4). But `()` shows `Expression expected.`

*AuthenticationManager.Test.vb*

```
 <TestMethod()> Public Sub Login()
    ' arrange
    Dim _controller As AuthenticationManager = New AuthenticationManager
    Dim httpContextBase As HttpContextBase = Mock < httpContextBase > ()

    ' Identiy

    Dim result As Boolean = _controller.Login(HttpContextBase, Identiy)

    ...
```

*AuthenticationManager.vb*

```
Public Shared Sub Login(httpContextBase As HttpContextBase, identity As ClaimsIdentity)
    Dim ctx = httpContextBase.Request.GetOwinContext()
    Dim authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication
    authenticationManager.SignIn(identity) ' Let's go Cookie!
End Sub
```

Do you can me help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the Mock and then get the object you want from it

```
<TestMethod()> Public Sub Login()
    ' arrange
    Dim _controller As AuthenticationManager = New AuthenticationManager
    Dim httpContextMock As Mock<HttpContextBase> = New Mock<HttpContextBase>()
    Dim httpContextBase As HttpContextBase = httpContextMock.Object
    ...
```

You were trying to declare a variable as `HttpContextBase` and initialize it as a `Mock < HttpContextBase >` plus you left out the `New` keyword in your original post

Finally [Don't mock HttpContext](https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2010/08/19/Dont-mock-HttpContext). He doesn't like to be mocked!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I'd like to test an owin implementation. In 4th row `< httpContextBase > = New Mock < HttpContextBase > ()` says `End of statement expected.`

Comment: There is nothing for me to test. You only provided a snippet of code with some syntax errors. That's what I based my answer on. Saying nothing happened when you haven't explained what the expected behavior is doesn't really provide any information for others to help does it? This answer addresses the stated problem in the original post. If there are other things to be fixed outside of what was originally shown then you need to ask a new question

Comment: You should read the article I linked to in my answer. Also this is now a completely new question to what was originally asked. The bait and switch is not appreciated. I will however try to help you as best I can

Comment: @JonasZielke. following up to see if you found a solution to your problem.

Comment: It's a complex article and i decided to stop the unit test for the owin middelware

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hope you eventually find a solution to your issue. Happy coding.